# Firebase dynamic links are not working on iOS when the dynamic link has the custom subdomain

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have integrated firebase dynamic links in my app as per the guidelines mentioned in [source1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive), [source2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFPo296OQqk). Everything is working as expected on the app for the default domains.

But when I create a [custom subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50793367/1996294) on firebase console and use it on the iOS device it's not working as expected(Even when the app is installed). I have added the new subdomain like **applinks:example.page.link** on **Capabilities=>Associated Domains** on my Xcode project.

Below is the straight scenario:

1) App is installed on the device.

2) Tapped on the dynamic link(with custom subdomain) https://example.page.link/abcXYZ on email.

3) It directly opened the app and `linkHandled` on my following code is always `false` and `completion` from `handleUniversalLink` function is never called.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                   restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

    if let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL {
      let linkHandled = FIRDynamicLinks.dynamicLinks()?.handleUniversalLink(incomingURL, completion: { (dynamiclink, error) in
        if let dynamiclink = dynamiclink, let _ =  dynamiclink.url {
          self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamiclink: dynamiclink)
        }
      })

      return linkHandled
    }

    return false
  }
```

But for the default domains created by firebase like https://my328.app.goo.gl/abcXYZ are working fine, `linkHandled` is always true, `completion` from `handleUniversalLink` is called and I'm receiving the expected `Deep link`(which is configured on firebase console) on `completion`.

Any thoughts on why Firebase dynamic links are not working on the app for custom subdomains? Do I need to configure anything additional than mentioned on the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive) for custom subdomains?

Comment: What version of the FDL library do you have installed? I'm wondering if older client libraries aren't able to handle custom subdomains.

Comment: @ToddKerpelman I'm using FirebaseDynamicLinks 1.4.0 and my projects' swift version is 3.2. When I remove and reinstall FirebaseDynamicLinks from Pod file, it still gets me 1.4.0 only, so I believe I'm using latest FDL library. FYI, I'm using Firebase (3.17.0), FirebaseAnalytics (3.9.0), FirebaseCore (3.6.0), FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.10), FirebaseMessaging (1.2.3).

Comment: @ToddKerpelman Did you get any clue?

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty old. The latest version of the FDL library is 3.0.1, which you would get from Firebase 5.3.0. You might want to do a full pod update, but keep in mind that will include a number of breaking changes, so make sure you back up your podfile.lock in case you need to revert.

Comment: @ToddKerpelman Thanks. For some reason, cocoa pods couldn't get me the latest version of FirebaseDynamicLinks, no matter what I do like remove and reinstall FirebaseDynamicLinks from Pod file or run pod update command. So, I have removed FirebaseDynamicLinks from pod file and ran the command pod install, it removed that library from my project and now I have downloaded FirebaseDynamicLinks framework from firebase console and integrated it manually on my project. Now with the new FirebaseDynamicLinks SDK, dynamic links with custom subdomain are working fine in the app :) Thanks!

Comment: I'm Using FirebaseDynamicLinks (3.1.1) and i have the same issue, HandledLink is always false with custom domain, and not calling the completion block

Comment: @ANeme, Not sure If the same issue occurs in FirebaseDynamicLinks (3.1.1). Check If we have further latest versions, If not report to the team.

Comment: handleUniversalLink is always returning false when using a custom domain (subdomain). Does anyone know if wildcards are required when specifying FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains keys? They use path definitions https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains, i only have https://[mysubdomain].example.com

Comment: @RyanRomanchuk were you able to figure it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because I was using FirebaseDynamicLinks 1.4.0 which is old. When I update to FDL library 3.0.1, dynamic links with custom subdomain are working fine in the app.

> The reason why I believed that I was using the latest FDL library and
>   couldn't identify that I was using old FDL library is, CocoaPods(a
>   dependency manager for iOS projects, [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22261196/1996294)) couldn't get me
>   the latest version of FirebaseDynamicLinks for some reason, no matter
>   what I do like remove and reinstall FirebaseDynamicLinks from Pod file
>   or run pod update command. So, I have removed FirebaseDynamicLinks
>   from pod file and ran the command pod install, it removed that library
>   from my project and now I have downloaded FirebaseDynamicLinks
>   framework from firebase console and integrated it manually on my
>   project. Now with the new FirebaseDynamicLinks SDK, dynamic links with
>   custom subdomain are working fine in the app.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Where did you download FirebaseDynamicLinks from in the Firebase Console?

Comment: I managed to update FirebaseDynamicLinks by first updating cocoapods then doing a pod update and this fixed my problem as well.  handleUniversalLink was previously returning false and the callback wasn't being called but now it is returning true and callback is being called as expected.

Comment: I actually have been with the same problem with version 2.0.0 of Firebase/DynamicLinks and couldn't go with higher version cuz of the swift language used in the project. Updating the pod to version 2.3.2 solved the problem and the function calls well then.
Thanks Ashok for sharing this :)

Answer (score 17):

If **custom** domain not working and **Google** domain working then you need to add ***FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains*** key to the ***info.plist*** for iOS

```
<key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
<array>
  <string>https://custom-domain.com</string>
</array>
```

> Ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you for the callout.

Comment: How to add this on Expo?